# Choose latest value from two table

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot

I have two tables, TableA and TableB. TableA has fields customValueA and timestamp, similarly TableB has fields customValueB and timeStamp. I have a variable customValue and want the latest of customValueA and customValueB to be assigned to it. Is there a way to write a SQL query for the same?

PS: Sorry if the questions makes no sense I am new to SQL

I can query the tables individually and get the fields from it, but I want to do it with a single query.

Comment: Please share the table structure, sample data, expected output and whatever you have tried till now.

Comment: You should provide some reproduceable sample SQL statements and data and also mention the DB you use.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two tables and want to join them, you could use union if the column types match:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA (
  id int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  customValueA int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  customDateA Date NOT NULL
);

 INSERT INTO tableA (id, customValueA, customDateA) VALUES
      ('1', '1', '2023-12-01'),
      ('2', '1', '2023-12-11'),
      ('3', '2', '2023-12-11'),
      ('4', '3', '2023-12-01');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableB (
  id int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  customValueB int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  customDateB Date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tableA (id, customValueA, customDateA) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2023-12-01'),
  ('2', '1', '2023-12-31'),
  ('3', '2', '2023-12-01'),
  ('4', '3', '2023-12-09');
```

The sql to get the max dates looks like this:

```
SELECT id, customValue, MAX(customDate) 
  FROM (
    SELECT id, 
          customValueA AS customValue,
          customDateA AS customDate
    FROM tableA
    UNION
    SELECT id, 
          customValueB AS customValue,
          customDateB AS customDate
    FROM tableB
  ) AS combined
  GROUP BY customValue
```

The result is this output:

| id | customValue | MAX(customDate) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-12-31 |
| 3 | 2 | 2023-12-11 |
| 4 | 3 | 2023-12-09 |

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26b4f7/1

Answer (score 1):

To get latest value, select values with date from all tables, into single dataset using UNION ALL, then apply row_number() over( order by date desc) and filter record with row_number=1

```
select customValue
from 
(
select customValue, customDate, row_number() over(order by customValue desc) as rn
(
SELECT    customValueA AS customValue,
          customDateA AS customDate
    FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
          customValueB AS customValue,
          customDateB AS customDate
    FROM tableB
) u

) s 
where rn=1
```